# How to make Wordpress core functions AND plugin functions available to cron loaded script

Tags: php, wordpress

I know about `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');` to make core functions available, but I am writing a php script that's loaded by a cron job that would also like to use functions from 2 plugins I have installed. Is there a similar include that will give access to my plugins functions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you just tried `require`-ing `wp-load.php` and then call the plugin functions? Because if the plugins are active, their functions would be loaded after the core functions in WordPress are loaded.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and weirdly it doesn't work

Comment: Try using the [WordPress cron API/functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/).